# Using the do statement in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, monads

Finally learning how to use monads in Haskell!

I want to read a file `testInput`, drop the first line, apply the function `waffles` to every other line, and save the result in a file `output.txt`.

I have written the following code:

```
main = do
    contents <- tail . fmap lines . readFile $ "testInput"
    result <- fmap waffles contents
    writeFile "output.txt" $ concat result

waffles row col = (row - 1)*(col - 1)
```

Sadly the compiler complains:

```
waffles.hs:3:41:
    Couldn't match type ‘IO String’ with ‘[String]’
    Expected type: FilePath -> [String]
      Actual type: FilePath -> IO String
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘readFile’
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘fmap lines . readFile’

waffles.hs:5:9:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[b]’ with actual type ‘IO ()’
    Relevant bindings include program :: [b] (bound at waffles.hs:2:1)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: writeFile "output.txt" $ concat result
    In the expression:
      do { contents <- tail . fmap lines . readFile $ "testInput";
           result <- fmap waffles contents;
           writeFile "output.txt" $ concat result }
    In an equation for ‘program’:
        program
          = do { contents <- tail . fmap lines . readFile $ "testInput";
                 result <- fmap waffles contents;
                 writeFile "output.txt" $ concat result }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I find that error quite daunting. Can you help me debug it?

I also would appreciate code style advice!

EDIT: I forgot to split the lines of the file and convert them to integers. I tried solving that as follows:

```
main = do
    contents <- tail . fmap lines . readFile $ "testInput"
    contents <- fmap read . words contents
    result <- fmap waffles contents
    writeFile "output.txt" $ concat result

waffles row col = (row - 1)*(col - 1)
```

But that only introduced more confusing compiler errors.

Comment: Before you start thinking about maybe using some kind of monad at some point in the future if the stars are just right, please explain what exactly `fmap waffles contents` does.

Comment: @n.m. Well `contents` should be a `IO String` type, and `fmap` maps a function to affect the insides of a monad, right?

Comment: I'll give you a hint for the first error: because you're composing `tail` with `fmap`, the compiler assumes you meant `fmap` to refer to `[]`'s version of `fmap` (`fmap lines :: [String] -> [[String]]`), not `IO`'s.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson yay progress! I substitued the first line to `contents <- fmap tail . fmap lines . readFile $ "testInput"` and now that one seems to work

Comment: Nice one! For the second error, have a think about what you expect the type of `contents` to be in the expression `fmap waffles contents`. (I wish Haskell had a decent interactive IDE so you could look at the types of variables in real time.)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson ghci has a not-decent way of achieving that. For example, here if I `:set -fdefer-type-errors; :set +c; :l test.hs; :type-at test.hs 2 4 2 13` (that last command has format start-line, start-column, end-line, end-column) I get `:: [String]`. But it's super finicky, doesn't appear to coordinate well with `:r` (or even with later `:l` commands), and having to muck about in your editor to get line and column numbers sucks. The `:all-types` command is significantly more verbose and less interactive, but ironically is more usable in some ways...

Comment: @DanielWagner Neat trick but not a very good UI! If the questioneer had been able to hover over an identifier and see a popup with the type, they probably would have been able to fix their own problem and wouldn’t have needed to even come to Stack Overflow

Comment: "Well contents should be a IO String type" Several errors here. One, the `<-` you are using is not for nothing, it gets you inside the monad so you don't have to fmap over it yourself. Two, from `lines` you get a `[String]` not a `String`. Three, `waffles` accepts two arguments, how exactly do you plan to use it to map over a `String` (or `IO String`, or `[String]`, or whatever) ? Four, these arguments are numbers, you are not supposed to multiply strings.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson For what it's worth, Emacs + Intero does that: when the cursor is on any variable, its type is shown. If you select a subexpression the type of that is shown. Errors and warnings are similarly shown when the cursor (or mouse pointer) is at the right spot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line in your `do` statement fails because you are trying to use `tail` on an `IO [String]`. You need to `fmap` the `tail` function:

```hs
contents <- fmap tail . fmap lines . readFile $ "testInput"
-- or....
contents <- fmap (tail . lines) . readFile $ "testInput"
```

Now you need a way to get every other line from `contents`. You could define a simple `everyOther` function for this:

```
everyOther :: [a] -> [a]
everyOther (x:_:xs) = x : everyOther xs
everyOther _        = []
```

And now you can chain that into your `fmap` in the first line:

```
contents <- fmap (everyOther . tail . lines) . readFile $ "testInput"
```

Your `waffles` function of `(row - 1)*(col - 1)` does not seem related to what I believe the type signature should be. Try starting with a type signature and building `waffles` from their. Based on your description, you are simply providing every other line to the function, so it should have signature:

```
waffles :: String -> String
```

Given that type signature for `waffles`, you can apply it via:

```
let result = fmap waffles contents
```

One more thing on the output: `concat` will smush all lines together. You probably want line breaks in there, so you might want to use `unlines` instead.

```
main = do
    contents <- fmap (everyOther . tail . lines) . readFile $ "testInput"
    let result = fmap waffles contents
    writeFile "output.txt" $ unlines result
```

Comment: The reason you need the "fmap" is that "readFile" gives you an "IO String" (i.e the string is inside the IO monad). You can't get the string out of the IO, but you can reach inside the IO and do stuff to the string in it, just like you can with any other container. "fmap" is the function that does this.

Comment: I think `fmap (tail . fmap)` is supposed to be `fmap (tail . lines)`.

Comment: Thanks @DarthFennec. I fixed the mistake